# Different Field serialization depends on set Accept type

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have field return System.Type and I know that it is not serializable. So I want to implement own serialization this fields depends Accept type chosen by user for example if chosen Json serialization I want to return string name of javascript type supported by .net, and when choose xml serialization return string name of Xsd type supported by .net.

It is possible to do this in .net class contains this field, or deeper in IDispatchMessageInspector or IDispatchMessageFormatter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have the type name as string (which is serialisable) and then on the other side of wire, turn it back to `Type`?

```
 Type t = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

Comment: For me important is that in this string was not .net type name, but xsd or javascript which I can choose in switch(dotNetType){return xsdType;}

Comment: In general, it's best practice to keep your WCF services as interoperable as possible.  In this case, Aliostad's advice helps you do that.